# Toolbar appearing blank on android activity

Tags: android, android-toolbar

My toolbar on top of my activity appears blank but it should have a navigation custom icon and a title but neither is visible?

Here is my xml

```html
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

here is my activity

```html
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_me)

        setupToolbar()

    }

    private fun setupToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_close)
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            onBackPressed()
        }

        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.profile_unfollow_warning)
        supportActionBar!!.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar!!.show()
    }

}
```

Theme i am using for this activity

```
       <activity android:name=".ui.profile.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity { 
// Declaring the Toolbar Object
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Create a xml file like tool_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp" />
```

Include the Toolbar into your main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/TextDimTop"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: U need to create an xml for toolbar and include it in your main activity like I show u in my answer above, please take a second look.

Comment: that diddnt fix it simply moving that into its own xml doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Opps, It seems to be a bug in ordering

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
supportActionBar?.setTitle(R.string.profile_unfollow_warning)
supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
toolbar?.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_close)
toolbar?.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        onBackPressed()
}
```

Comment: that does not work. supportActionbar is null at that point unless you invoke and set the actionbar. the last call on your snippet

Comment: No it doesnt. you simply reverted your changes to mimic the exact same as the one i posted.

It still blank, the toolbar has no title no icons, nothing

Comment: could you post the theme you are using for this activity?

Comment: OK done. edited my post. if i dont use .NoActionBar and use another theme like Light or Dark, the app will crash if i try to set my own toolbar

Comment: yes if you used theme with Actionbar , you have a ready made one , you don't create your own one in that case

Comment: could you try to change android:background for `AppBarLayout` to color other than white and see?

Comment: ahh yes i can see the title text now! wjy was it set to white? i have not set it to any colour?  I still cant see the navigation icon i set which is a simply a cross button that should go on the left side of the toolbar